# XPath or how to get the elements in Angular2

Tags: robotframework

I am new to Angular2. Need to pick up the `showDataPopup` using robot framework.

```
<div class="date date-range" ng-click="showDatePopup();">
    January 13, 2018 - February 13, 2018
</div>
```

How to grab value from pop-up element?

Comment: <div class="date date-range" ng-click="showDatePopup();">January 13, 2018 - February 13, 2018</div>

Comment: Based on the post you've made, I would recommend spending some time reading documentation in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) so that you have the best chance at getting your question answered.

Comment: Did you mean to grab date value `January 13, 2018 - February 13, 2018` from `<div>` tag?

Comment: I am looking a way to select from date to to date using tag